# I want to return the value of a PHP Array with automatic loop index and into a string

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have array $Computer with value:

```
array(1) {
    [0]=> array(4) {
            [0]=> string(1) "0"
            [1]=> string(10) "Produksi01"
            [2]=> string(12) "172.16.44.25"
            [3]=> string(28) "Wednesday, 13 May 2020 01:07" 
    } 
}
```

I want return the value of the array without having to write the index is one-on-one like this *$computer[0][1]*, i want it like automatic only with one line code for all output,

I've tried this line of code but it not working, output error undifined offset

```
foreach( $computer as $row ){
    for($i=0; $i<=count($computer[0]); $i++){   
        $result = "$row[$i]";
    }
}
```

my expect the $result variable that contains an array can be assigned to be part of the query.

```
query = "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ($result)";
```

my expectation output is a variable result become like this :

```
"INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('0','Produksi01','172.16.44.25','Wednesday, 13 May 2020 01:07')"
```

and can be executed into the database

```
$db->query($query)
```

I want create a class where there is a very reusable createData function that can be used by simply replacing the value of array/value input

Comment: Check out [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements with placeholder values** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: you would use https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php instead of a loop but that would make you vulnurable as @tadman said

Comment: @nbk Stay far, far away from `implode` for database values like this.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming $computer is like this:

```
$computer = [
    ['0','Produksi01','172.16.44.25','Wednesday, 13 May 2020 01:07'],
    ['1','Products02','127.0.0.1','Wednesday, 13 May 2020 02:00'], 
];
```

Running the following snippet:

```
<?php $computer = [
        [
            '0',
             'Produksi01',
             '172.16.44.25',
             'Wednesday, 13 May 2020 01:07'
        ],
        [
            '1',
            'Products02',
            '127.0.0.1',
            'Wednesday, 13 May 2020 02:00'
            ]
    ];



var_dump($computer);

$results = '';
foreach ($computer as $row){
    $results .= "INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('{$row[0]}','{$row[1]}','{$row[2]}','{$row[3]}');".PHP_EOL;
}

echo $results;
```

will produce the following output:

```
$php main.php
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "Produksi01"
    [2]=>
    string(12) "172.16.44.25"
    [3]=>
    string(28) "Wednesday, 13 May 2020 01:07"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "Products02"
    [2]=>
    string(9) "127.0.0.1"
    [3]=>
    string(28) "Wednesday, 13 May 2020 02:00"
  }
}
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('0','Produksi01','172.16.44.25','Wednesday, 13 May 2020 01:07');
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('1','Products02','127.0.0.1','Wednesday, 13 May 2020 02:00');
```

then you can execute this insertion at once.

If this program is public on the web, you should check out **PDO** / **MySQLi** because otherwise it will be vulnerable to attackers.

Comment: Please don't post code full of SQL injection holes and pretend it's fine. You know it's not. A PDO or `mysqli` example would go a long way towards making this answer safe *and* educational.